# How To Optimize JSF applications

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

*I'm rewriting the questions to expand to broader context.*

I would like to optimize my JSF web application by minifying CSS and JS, optimizing AJAX requests and basically learning the rules of efficient JSF web apps.

Emphasis on JSF since much of the page is built by the JSF framework although there are client side Javascript files that need optimization as well..

Comment: Optimization is a very broad topic. What do you want to optimize? Also, *all* optimizations should be preceded by a phase of profiling, to identify performance-bottlenecks. This should be your first question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using richfaces:

> ```
> <context-param>
>     <param-name>org.ajax4jsf.COMPRESS_SCRIPT</param-name>
>     <param-value>true</param-value>
> </context-param>
>
> <context-param>
>     <param-name>org.richfaces.LoadStyleStrategy</param-name>
>     <param-value>all</param-value>
> </context-param>
>
> <context-param>
>     <param-name>org.richfaces.LoadScriptStrategy</param-name>
>     <param-value>all</param-value>
> </context-param>
> ```

More info on this [blog](http://www.javaplex.com/blog/optimizing-jsf-richfaces-applications/)

Optimizing the ajax call is a too much generic question, it depends much on the widget library you are using. Try to be specific, otherwise this question may be closed.

Comment: Tnx. I'll close  it and think of another question.